# Date issue on multilanguage posts

Tags: wordpress

I have a multilanguage site with posts. Post in one language are ok and date displayed is published date. In the other language always is displayed todays' date.

What can be a problem?

entry-content.php

```
    <!-- Blog date -->
<?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'blog_date', true ) ) { ?>
    <div class="educon-blog-date">
        <?php $the_date = get_the_date(); ?>
        <?php echo date_i18n("d", strtotime($the_date)); ?> <span><?php echo date_i18n("M Y", strtotime($the_date)) ?></span>
    </div>
<?php } ?> 
<!-- end date -->

<!-- Blog author & comments -->
<?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'blog_author', true ) || get_theme_mod( 'blog_comment', true ) ) { ?>
    <ul class="blog-post-meta"> 
        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'blog_author', true ) ) { ?>
            <li class="meta-date">

                <span class="img-author"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <?php if ( get_the_author_meta('first_name') != "" || get_the_author_meta('last_name') != "" ) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_author_meta('first_name');?> <?php echo get_the_author_meta('last_name');?></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php the_author_posts_link() ?>  
                <?php }?>
            </li>
        <?php }?>

        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'blog_category', true ) ) { ?>
            <li><i class="fa fa-eraser" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?></li>
        <?php }?>

        <!-- Comments section -->
        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'blog_comment', true ) ) { ?>
            <?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) ) : ?>
                <li class="meta-comment">
                    <i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i>
                    <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . esc_html__( '0', 'wpeducon' ) . '</span>', esc_html__( '1', 'wpeducon' ), esc_html__( '% comments', 'wpeducon' ) ); ?>
                </li>
            <?php endif; //.comment-link ?>
        <?php }?> 
        <!-- comments section end -->
    </ul>

<?php } ?>


<!-- Blog Title -->
<div class="entry-header">
    <h2 class="entry-title blog-entry-title">
        <?php if ( is_single() ) {?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php }?>
        <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged()) { ?>
        <span class="featured-post"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
        <?php } ?>
    </h2> <!-- //.entry-title --> 
</div>
<!-- Blog title End -->
```

Above is code from entry-content.php

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: when you published the BOSNIAN language post

Comment: Jul 15, 2016. The same day when English post was published.

Comment: Wehn I go to edit posts, it says Published on: Jul 15, 2016 @ 15:19, but it show todays' date on posts.

Comment: share your single.php file

Comment: I edited question

Comment: post-format/content.php share this file

Comment: I edited question again

Comment: share this file post-format/entry-content.php

Comment: I Edited question

Comment: I Think there is a issue with this line og code
 <?php echo date_i18n("d", strtotime($the_date)); ?> <span><?php echo date_i18n("M Y", strtotime($the_date)) ?></span>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159553/discussion-between-ndoe-and-rajkumar-gour).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a custom date format in general settings. When I changed it dates on posts chaned too.